# Using conda installed in Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, package-managers

I want to use conda install command in Virtualenv but do not know how to do that.

I did following things:

First I created a Virtualenv called tensorflow2

```
module load python/3.5
virtualenv tensorflow2
source tensorflow2/bin/activate
```

I checked which conda I am using:

```
(tensorflow2) [sky8@gra-login3 ~]$ which conda
~/miniconda3/bin/conda
```

then I did:

```
pip install conda
```

I checked again:

```
(tensorflow2) [sky8@gra-login3 ~]$ which conda
~/tensorflow2/bin/conda
```

At this point, I thought I was using conda in this tensorflow2 virtual env. However, when I did conda list, the output is exactly the same as conda outside virtual env, not a separate conda.

When I tried to import packages in conda list, I failed. I am confused with the relationship between Virtualenv and conda, and how to make the two things compatible.

For clarification: I have to use Compute Canada's pre-built Python wheels to install [tensorflow](https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Tensorflow), so I can not use conda virtual env, and I need to use conda install to deal with some dependencies.

Comment: I would have thought you should start by installing Anaconda (or miniconda), create a conda environment with `conda create ...`, activate it, then finally use `pip` to install tensorflow from your prebuilt wheels. Does that not work for some reason?

Comment: @nekomatic That was the first solution came to my mind. But when I import tensorflow, this error happened: ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/sky8/miniconda3/envs/cal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so) . I asked system manager, and he said :This looks like you have conflicting glibc version requirements across your libraries. This is generally caused by trying to combine the module software from the system software.

Comment: Why do you need to use Compute Canada's pre-built Python wheels to install tensorflow? Can't you install it from [here][1] using Anaconda? 

At any rate, I would try to use Anaconda's virtual env, rather than installing Anaconda in 'virtualenv'.



  [1]: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow

Comment: @ScottSkiles 1.Since I was building environment on HPC(national computation clusters) as a user not admin, I have to to use tensorflow pre-built wheels which is tailored for this system. 2 I can't install it via Anaconda.
 After communicating with system managers, I successfully built the environment I want by not using conda, instead using pip to built every package from wheels.  Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I employ virtualenv not only for Python code, but also for all other programming languages because, ultimately, I just need executables installed onto separate directories from system software. Why conda don't simply employ virtualenv as a requirement like everyone else? Why conda has to reinvent the wheel?